# Max-width issue with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

a newbie here.

I'm trying to learn responsive design and in doing so had just come across max-width prob with ie9 while it works as I expected in Chrome. It simply just wont adjust the max width of an image I'm trying to scale when I adjust the browser window. Let me just show you the html code and the css.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>This is a test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/resetmin.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test3.css" />  
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:black; height:35px;"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
        <h1>This is my header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="image001.jpg" alt="Just a picture 815px width and 500px height"></img> 
        </div>
        <div class="imageControl">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<div class="content">
        <div class="header">
        <h1>This is my header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="image002.jpg" alt="Just a picture 500px width and 815px height"></img> 
        </div>
        <div class="imageControl">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBar"></div>
    <div class="padding"></div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: #555; width: 960px; height: 485px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code: test3.css

```
body {
color: #333;
font: 100%/1.5 Cambria, Georgia, serif;
background: #ece6d6 url(_assets/bg-light.png) repeat;
/* margin: 0 auto; */
}

img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
}

#container {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #aaa;
}

.header {
height: 40px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.content {
background-color: grey;
float: left;
margin: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
}

.pic {
width: auto;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #777;
float: left;
/* position: relative;
top: 15px;
left: 15px; */
}   

.imageControl {
width: 85px;
height: 350px;
background-color: #ccc;
float: right;
/* position: relative;
top: 15px;
left: 15px; */
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}

.padding {
padding-bottom: 15px;
clear: both;
}

.sideBar {
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
margin: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
float: right;
background-color: #333;
}

h1 {
font: bold 1.6em Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

#container {
    width: 95%;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 30%;
}
.sidebar .widget {
    padding: 8% 7%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

}
```

Please take a look and review it. It is still a work in progress, so please don't mind the messy responsive design when u adjust the browser (my problem rite now is the image, as it won't scale down in ie9).

Thanks. And if there is still something unclear, pls ask and I will try to respond to it.

Comment: Help, anyone? I'm really stuck with this, I tried googling it and no reference regarding this issue i'm having.

Comment: Code sample is a tad long... http://sscce.org/ Glad you found your answer though :)

Answer (score 3):

Found it. After a lot of tinkering, this is my solution as for now. This it what i add/edit in my html and css codes.

Edited HTML code:

```
<div class="pic">
   <img class="imageObject" src="image001.jpg" alt="Just a picture 815px width and 500px height"></img> 
</div>
```

Added CSS code:

```
img.imageObject {
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
max-width:50.3975em;
}
```

As for why, I'm still looking for the explanation why. But rite now this will do the trick for me.

Comment: Adding `width:100%` forced IE9 to respect `max-width` for me as well. Still not aware of the underlying cause, however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible fix:

CSS:

```
.scale
{
    max-width:980px;
}
.scale img
{
    display:block;
    max-width:80% //your value
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="scale">
    <img src="...."/>
</div>
```